# facebook button cropping to size of span

Tags: facebook, overflow

I am completely flumoxed on this one. I have a Facebook button that seems to be hidding the overflow but only on the y axis???

You can see it live here: [www.new.thebespokeflorist.co.uk/blog](http://www.new.thebespokeflorist.co.uk/blog) just scroll down and mouse over the facebook icon below a blog post.

The facebook button is held in a div:

```
<div class="share-facebook social-noshow" onclick="toggleSocial()">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="lucida grande"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.social-show { width: 60px; overflow: auto; }
.social-noshow { width: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
.share-facebook { background: url('http://www.new.thebespokeflorist.co.uk/wp-content/themes/V3 TBF/images/blog/fb.png') left bottom no-repeat; height: 20px; float: left; padding: 0 0 0 30px; transition: width 0.25s ease 0s; }
.share-facebook:hover { width: 90px; transition: width 0.25s ease 0s; overflow: visible; }
```

The onclick() java is:

```
<script>function toggleSocial() {
    var noShow = document.getElementById("social-noshow");
    noShow.classList.toggle("social-show"); }</script>
```

As far as I can tell the button is croping within the span width of the facebook button itself which is 71px. If I increase the span width I can see more of the comment box.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

I have also tested loading the facebook button elswhere on the site and I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out. I had further up in my CSS a 'fix' for Iframes that made them 100% span. Removing that fixed my problem.